# Why doesn't this CSS work in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

This works fine in Chrome, but not in IE8. It should just give a light-colored blue background with rounded corners and a drop shadow to the div:

```
.ppanel
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}
```

Comment: because ie8 doesn't support rounded corners and shadows (at least with the CSS you have)

Comment: IE8 does not support the box shadow property (IE9 does, though). You can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to use some of the features in older versions of IE.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, guys. I'll see if we can use IE9 for this project. If not, I'll look into the workaround you all suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet explorer 8 does not support rounded corners by default. You can get the result you want however by using a tool like [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: Just wanted to say the CSS PIE is roughly 80Kb of extra weight, and all you are doing is extending an experience to users who don't use a modern browser... thus stifling the progression of the web.  Please let IE7 and IE8 users have a sub-experience so as to provoke them to upgrade... please :)

Comment: I know this thread is 3 years old at this point, but I feel the need to mention that some large companies with other, more important things on their plate STILL haven't upgraded default browsers. It's 2015 and the company I'm interning with is still using IE8. That's why I ended up here. I'd much prefer an upgrade, but it's not at the top of IT's list.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer did not support `border-radius` until IE9. You will find detailed information here: http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners.